# Как с HTTP ответом передается html и css код?

Tags: http

Сидел я спокойно и вдруг задумался над тем, как передаются данные по http и вдруг меня осинило, что помимо простой страницы, описанной с помощью html также есть и css, который добавляет стили к идентифицированным частям html кода. Дело в том, что в http ответе прописываются заголовки и само тело ответа(html код), но тут не ясно, каким образом передается css код, ибо в заголовках ни намека на это нет. Типо браузер обращается к тому, что указано в , чтобы понять, откуда брать файл с css кодом или как? Извиняйте, если запутал вопросом, я толком и не знаю, как его задать, как можно подробней попытался описать его.

Comment: Браузер просто отправляет ещё один http-запрос по указанной ссылке для скачивания css-файла, сервер соответственно отвечает.

Comment: А почему вы пишите комментарием, а не ответом, щас-то мне уже ответили, но если бы ваш ответ был первее, я бы не сиог его назначить решением.

Answer (score 2):

Также как и HTML, JavaScript, изображения и т. д. После получения кода HTML браузер считывает указанные в коде ссылки на CSS, JavaScript файлы и изображения и отправляет дополнительные запросы на получение этих файлов.